# Calculating back-reaction forces for an ensemble of slowly moving, classical charges

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics

Suppose you have a set of charges that are Newtonian (not quantum and not fast-moving) point particles. They are subject to known (but not necessarily constant) external forces ($F_{ext}$), as well as mutual electrostatic forces ($F_s$).

We want to estimate the *electromagnetic* forces ($F_m$) on each charge; these forces will over time sap energy form the system. We want an estimate of $F_m$ that is accurate, in other words the *relative* error in $F_m$ goes to zero in the Newtonian limit ($F_m$ itself will go to zero as well, thus my specification of relative and not absolute error). Is there a way to estimate this easily (without resorting to Maxwell's equations)? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{F}_m(\mathbf{r}_m)=\mathbf{F}_{ext}(\mathbf{r}_m)+q_m \sum_{i\ne m}q_i\mathbf{n}_{im}/(\mathbf{r}_m-\mathbf{r}_i)^2$, isn't it? Or you want magnetic forces too?

EDIT: For magnetic part, you can use the Lagrangian from Landau-Lifshitz textbook (§65):

[image]

Comment: "We want to estimate the electromagnetic forces" Yes, the magnetic force is the main point of the question. Read it carefully.

Comment: @KevinKostlan: I added a reference to a textbook.